# How to pass a DateTime value as parameter in Java Driver for Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I am using the Neo4J Java driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I am trying to use a DateTime value as value in a parameter map roughly like this:

```
// we have a timezone, unixTimestamp as epoch seconds and a simple key: "d"
final Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(unixTimestamp);
final ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of(timezone);
final ZonedDateTime zonedValueDate = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
// creating a DateTimeValue from zonedValueDate does not work either
return Map.of(key, zonedValueDate);
```

This map is used in an instance of `TransactionWork` like

```
public Map<String,Object> execute(Transaction tx) {
    Result queryResult = tx.run(query, parameter);
    // consuming results ...
    // returning them as Map
}
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof
```

A `DateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` [should be allowed as parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/cypher-workflow/#driver-type-mapping) ([here is another hint](https://community.neo4j.com/t/unable-to-convert-to-neo4j-value-java-bolt-driver/14325/2)), but how can it be used correctly?

Or do I **HAVE** to create a DateTime value like [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/temporal/#functions-datetime-temporal):

```
datetime({year:1984, month:10, day:11, hour:12, timezone: 'Europe/Stockholm'})
```

Comment: Looks right to me. ZonedDateTime should work. Can we see your actual query string ?

Comment: Oh it was an embarrassing bug: I have used the map as value in another map and the latter one as parameter map. Not they are flattened and it works.